# Unable to query dynamically named range on Excel sheet using ADO

Tags: vba, excel, ado, jet

Suppose I have an Excel Sheet named `Adjustments` stored in a variable called `wksName` and, on that sheet, I have a named range defined as follows if you look in the Name Manager:

```
tblData =OFFSET(Adjustments!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Adjustments!$A:$A),4)
```

So that it expands to as many rows as we have data in columns A thru D.

Now I have the following code in my VBA module:

```
Set ExcelCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set ExcelRecSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

ExcelCon.ConnectionString = "Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';" & _
                            "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
                            "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"

'Get the data for the update:
ExcelCon.Open

' Get the data from the spreadhseet for the update statement
Set ExcelRecSet = ExcelCon.Execute("SELECT * FROM [" & wksName & "$tblData]")
```

When I try and run this code, I get the error:

```
Run-time error '-2147217865 (80040e37)':
The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$tblData'.
Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

Is this a limitation to using ADO - Named ranges can not be dynamically defined - Or is there a way I can get this to work?

Thanks!!

Comment: Try this... `Set ExcelRecSet = ExcelCon.Execute("SELECT * FROM tblData")`

Comment: or something like `Set ExcelRecSet = ExcelCon.Execute("SELECT * FROM [" & wksName & "$" & tblData.Address & "]")`

Comment: Thanks, @SiddharthRout, I did end up getting it to work with `Set ExcelRecSet = ExcelCon.Execute("SELECT * FROM [" & wksName & "$" & wks.Range("tblData").Address(0, 0) & "]")`, but I'd really like to know if there is a nicer way....

Comment: Didn't the first one work for you?>

Comment: Sadly, no - I even tried to make the range `tblData` scope to the workbook rather than the sheet, but still no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the code that ended up working for me (for those of you that may find you have the same issue) was something along the lines of:

```
Set ExcelRecSet = ExcelCon.Execute("SELECT * FROM [" & wksName & "$" & _
                                    wks.Range("tblData").Address(0, 0) & "]")
```

This definitely works, but if there was a way to select a variable range without having to reference it as above, I'd love to see the way to do that.

Thanks!!

Comment: what is `wks` in this? is it one of `schemaRow`s in `schemaTable.Rows` which `connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable()` returns?

Comment: @Mehrad, no, it would be the regular sheet, like `Sheet1`.

Comment: Just to clarify, do I need a `new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()` to access the `Sheet1` you mentioned? cuz as far as I know `GetOleDbSchemaTable()` won't give you a `Range` property for the sheet which it returns in the sheets (called `Tables`).
Oh, I just read the question again at it seems the OP didn't even use the `OleDbConnection` and I must have missed it in the heat of the moment since the starting of the question was exactly is the same as the issue I have. (and also there is a select)

Comment: @Mehrad, it seems you have a completely different problem... Read my question and the solution posted - My solution solves my question, but it seems you are looking for something else... Maybe post it as a separate question I and others could try and help you solve....