# Can "dynamic named ranges" in excel be access using OLEDB connection?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, oledb, ole

I am trying to access a [dynamic named range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) with the following formula which is frequently used for this purpose.

```
=offset(...,0,0,counta(...),...)
```

> ***Dynamic Named Range***  "*In Microsoft Excel, you may have a named range that must be extended to include new information. This article
>   describes a method to create a dynamic defined name.*"

However, `OleDbConnection` is unable to recognize this object and throws the generic error of *"The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Arg4a'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."*

Here and there I have read that `dynamic named ranges` can't be used in this method, however I wanted a confirmation on this then I can go on and think of an alternative.

As you can see below, Excel doesn't list the `value` for the dynamic version. I can easily access `_Arg3` in any scope (Workbook, or specific sheet) but no luck with Arg4.

[image]

I am using a simple select such as below for the Global named ranges:

```
var select = "SELECT * FROM _Arg4";
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(select, conn);
```

and the following `connection string`

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=1\""
```

- *I have also tagged `vba` in this since this situation can be implemented with this language as well and I used lots of sources related to `vba` to learn the general idea.*
- The full body of the method I am using is here under **XLS import** at: [Import Excel File to DataSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32370/Import-Excel-File-to-DataSet)

Comment: Any luck with something like this: `"SELECT * FROM " + xlApp.xlWorkbook.xlWorksheet.Range("Arg4").Address;` ?

Comment: Actually when I was researching this I have seen a similar code something like `wks.Range(...).Address(0,0);` and no previous code to this that I can find out what is the type of wks. cuz I couldn't find anything (like sheets, tables and etc) which has a `range` property. But based on what you mentioned, doesn't this totally against the fact that I am using OleDb? I think to use this I need to refer to a traditional way of creating a `new Application()` and go from there which slows down everything. (At least reading the data in this method was extremely slow I should say).

Comment: Ahhh yes you would need to instantiate an `Excel.Application` object in order to access *workbook*, *worksheet*, and *range* objects. And yes: that would probably go against using OLEDB.  I didn't even think of that... so the problem is that without the `Excel.Application`, those named ranges probably don't mean anything...

Comment: Well, using OleDb connection I can read the data limited by the **named range** rather than the whole sheet and these **named ranges** show up in the list which is returned by `connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable()`. But as soon as you add a formula to the `named range` to make a `dynamic named range`, poof!, it doesn't show up in the list anymore.

Comment: Hmmmm well I'm stumped. All I can find suggests like you said: it can't be done -- unless you open the workbook object, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539173/unable-to-query-dynamically-named-range-on-excel-sheet-using-ado

Comment: As an aside: I can't execute an `ExcelCon.ConnectionString` *unless* I have an instance of Excel already open. I can't test this in c# but I am trying to run this late-bound from other office applications, and the connection will only work if Excel.Application is a running process.  If that is also true for you, then it should make not much difference, just instantiate the workbook/worksheet/range objects as per the answer I linked to above.

Comment: @DavidZemens, hahaha... I was actually asking questions from the person who respond to the question you mentioned earlier. from his comment I can tell the `wks` he mentioned is exactly what you pointed out. However, I don't have an instance of an Excel in my code( at least not to my knowledge). I am using the **XLS import** method suggested in this post http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32370/Import-Excel-File-to-DataSet